# How do you utilize local storage to increment poll tallies?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I'm trying to make it so these poll tallies are incremented and stored in local storage if selected. I've got the poll count working, but I'm struggling on how to increment individually for each of the three choices and save it to local storage.

```js
let pollCount = 0;

function getPollCount() {
  return "Total Votes: " + pollCount;
}
function incrementPollCount() {
  let nominee1 = document.getElementById("ges");
  let nominee2 = document.getElementById("glp");
  let nominee3 = document.getElementById("prs");

  if (nominee1.checked) {
    pollCount++;
  } else if (nominee2.checked) {
    pollCount++;
  } else if (nominee3.checked) {
    pollCount++;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>Please Select Nominee!</h2>
  <form  name="nominee" onsubmit="voteSubmit()">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" 
         name="nominee" id="ges" value="Gibson ES-335">
    </label> Gibson ES-335
    <div id="orderTotal1">
      <p id="p1"></p>
      <script>document.write(getPollCount())</script>
    </div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" 
             name="nominee" id="glp" value="Gibson Les Paul">
    </label>
      Gibson Les Paul
      <div id="orderTotal2">
        <p id="p2"></p>
        <script>document.write(getPollCount())</script>
      </div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" 
              name="nominee" id="prs" value="Paul Reed Smith">
   </label> 
     Paul Reed Smith
     <div id="orderTotal3">
       <p id = "p3"></p>
       <script>document.write(getPollCount())</script>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" 
         name="select" value="Select" onsubmit="incrementPollCount()">
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: How do you want to save the data at the `localStorage`? You can use [localStorage.setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 1):

You can just store 3 different values in the localstorage like so:

```js
function getPollCount() {
    return "Total Votes: " + getIndividualPollCount('nom1') + getIndividualPollCount('nom2') + getIndividualPollCount('nom3');
}

function updateCount(entry) {
    localStorage.setItem(entry, (Number(localStorage.getItem(entry)) || 0) + 1)
}

function getIndividualPollCount(entry) {
    Number(localStorage.getItem(entry) || 0)
}

function incrementPollCount() {
    let nominee1 = document.getElementById("ges");
    let nominee2 = document.getElementById("glp");
    let nominee3 = document.getElementById("prs");

    if (nominee1.checked) {
        updateCount('nom1')
    } else if (nominee2.checked) {
        updateCount('nom2')
    } else if (nominee3.checked) {
        updateCount('nom3')
    }
}
```